# Turning a page title text 90 degrees using CSS

Tags: css, text, rotation

I've been toying with this for 2 days. Besides being frustrated about getting it to line up - I realized that maybe this won't be possible due to each page's title being different 'widths' (and because text goes from left to right, the longer the title name the more it grows UP into the header area).  The other consideration is, this is for a WordPress site (not that it really matters).

I've found tutorials where this is being used for the 'date stamps' for blog entries, where the only text being rotated is either a 4 digit year or a 2 digit date.

The graphic design:

[image]

Where I've gotten so far with the CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/vGFZP/

Comment: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation

Answer (score 2):

You just need to play with the `padding` and `margin`

Try this (#s just for example)

```
.title {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 35px;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 45px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    margin-top: 100px;  /* ADD THIS */
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-left: 150px;  /* ADD THIS */
}
```

Comment: I added your margin-top and the padding-left  :) Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so it worked on the small example I had, but now it isn't quite behaving on my WordPress CSS  http://www.startingpointstables.com/wp-content/themes/aSPS2010/A-Theme2.html   (I added the border and background colors so I could see where/what the divs were doing ). I got it close, any way to move the 'title' (Pony School) to the left about 5 px?   If I use the Top: & Left: for the absolute then it positions it from the corner of the browser (so when the browser resizes then the title stays in it's spot) and relative doesn't work at all.

Comment: Looks ok @KBarnes.  Are you still looking for help with it?

Comment: Actually yes... HA HA!  So I have it all working... except one nasty side effect.  You can't access (click) the links in the text in the div 'below' (next) to the rotated one.  *dumbfounded look* http://www.startingpointstables.com/horse-boarding/  http://www.startingpointstables.com/category/kayes-blog/

Answer (score 1):

To fit any title length, make a placeholder with the same height and width (eg. 960 x 960px). Make this placeholder big to fit longer titles. Also align text to the right, then it will float to the page top.

See demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/4QFPJ/4/

```css
.title {
   display:block;
   position:absolute;
   font-size:50px;
   font-weight:bold;
   line-height:45px;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

   float: left;
   left:25px;
   top: 20px;
   height:960px;
   width: 960px;
   text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so it worked on the small example I had, but now it isn't quite behaving on my WordPress CSS  http://www.startingpointstables.com/wp-content/themes/aSPS2010/A-Theme2.html

Comment: *** EDITED - Never mind! I paid attention to the class for the actual title and it had a line height. :)

Comment: Thanks! This is great. However, if you need to click on or select anything in the content div you'll need to add a negative z-index to the title div.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript could do that for you. Also jQuery has the .width() function… But it's not a nice way… I will play a little bit around.